# Custom tab using CSS

Tags: html, css

I have this css style:

```
span.smalltab{
    padding: 0 64px;
}
```

How could I make a customtab so that I could enter desired value in HTML? Could it be done something like that:

```
<span class = 'customtab = 20px'>
```

The last line is there to just illustrate my problem better (I know it doesn't work that way).

Comment: It is unclear what you're asking...

Comment: I want to have a span.customtab {} where I could set some variable. Then I would access that value in HTML by telling CSS how much space in px it should span.

Comment: Give it another class, the styles will override the original, [**like this**](http://jsfiddle.net/4JY52/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create another class and use it:

```
<style>
.customtab {
    padding: 0 20px;
}
</style>

<span class="customtab"></span>
```

---

If you need a different value every time, you can customise element appearance from HTML with inline styles:

```
<span style="padding: 0 20px">
```

This declaration will have higher priority that the one placed inside `<style>` or external CSS file. Be warned than using inline styles could be a maintenance nightmare: you'll end up with styles everywhere. Use it only if you absolutely *must*.